# What are Refs in React or React-Native and what is the importance of using them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

While going through react documentation I came across Refs. I want to know why Refs are used, what is purpose of using them. I haven't used them before in any previous projects. Some people suggest avoid using Refs, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.