# Why use refs in react? What is the use cases for it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question exists but it didn't give a lot of data or real world explanation: [What are Refs in React or React-Native and what is the importance of using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475921/what-are-refs-in-react-or-react-native-and-what-is-the-importance-of-using-them)

Let's say i want to integrate to 3rd party library how ref is going to help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some 3rd party libraries expose methods to interact with their components.

For example, in `react-native-elements` npm, they have `shake` method for `Input` component. You can use this method to shake `Input` element when user input is invalid.

Common use case is as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const input = React.createRef();

return (
  <View>
    <Input
      ref={input}
      onTextChange={(text) => setValue(text)}
    />
    <Button 
      title={'Submit'}
      onPress={() => {
        if (!isValid(value)) {
          input.current.shake();
        }
      }}
    />
  </View>
);
```

This is react native example, but the similar goes to react projects. I hope you get the picture. Animations like shake cannot be easily handled with state, so it's better to use `useRef` to call component methods directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say i want to integrate to 3rd party library how ref is going to help me?

Refs let you access the DOM directly, thus you can use vanilla js libraries using refs, for example you could use jQuery like `$(ref)`. This simplifies and makes getting DOM nodes less error prone than using other techniques such as adding classes/ids to every element and then using selectors since these methods do not stop you from accessing nodes not created by you.

*Long story short, `Refs` let you treat react elements as though they were vanilla js*

Comment: Why not just use a normal local variable for this ? I mean you could document.querySelector and get any element, Why refs ?

Comment: @theMyth, The main reason is that refs are inside the react ecosystem, this means that if the ref changes, your component will automatically rerender, which will not happen if you use pure js; Furthermore, with refs, you do not necessarily have to make a unique id or class pattern, which can become problematic if you decide to reuse some component multiple times, and only one should have a function call, and not the other.

Answer (score 2):

React useRef help us to accessing dom elements before its rendering.
You can go through it

> https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to use the properties of child from a parent, we refer it with a ref id, this is to ensure we are executing on the right child component. The properties can be either states, props of functions defined in the child component.